# Cannot refer to the static enum field Cbev2Key.log within an initializer

Tags: java, enums, constructor, log4j2

I am currently using @Log4j2 in my enum class like this:

```
import lombok.extern.log4j.Log4j2;
@Log4j2
public enum Cbev2Key
{
....
....
}
```

I am using this "log" variable in the code to put logs like this in the constructor:

```
CbeV2Key(final String value, final IonType type,final boolean isMandatoryKey)
    {
        if(StringUtils.isEmpty(value) || type == null) {
            log.fatal("Empty/Null value/type not permitted value : " + value + " type : " + type);

        }

        this.type = type;
        this.isMandatoryKey = isMandatoryKey;
    }
```

In the log variable it is showing me this error

> "Cannot refer to the static enum field Cbev2Key.log within an initializer."

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lombok's `@Log4j2`  annotation generates a static `log` field:

https://projectlombok.org/api/lombok/extern/log4j/Log4j2.html

But Enum elements are initialized before static fields are.

Therefore, the constructor of an Enum cannot access uninitialized statics like a logger.

Comment: yeah , that is fine but the variables I am mentioning in the constructor are not static, these all are just private fields.

Comment: @mshikher `log` is static. It's in the error message.

Comment: how can I fix this up ? how can I log if I can't do it this way?

Comment: @mshikher Try using  `LogManager.getLogger(Cbev2Key.class)` directly in the constructor instead of the `log` variable.